# Django rest framework ignores has_object_permission

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to limit the access to objects for users. Only creaters should modify objects. For that purpose like they say in tutorial I've written

```
class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return False
```

and added it to permission_classes. But still any user can modify any object.
If I add method

```
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return False
```

nobody can do anything. So all behaviour is controlled by the only has_permission method that doesn't provide any way to handle per object permissions.
So am I doing something wrong? Here's the code of request handler

```
class ProblemsHandler(APIView):

    permission_classes = (
        IsOwnerOrReadOnly,
        permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
    )

    def pre_save(self, request, problem):
        problem.author = request.user

    def get_object(self, request, pk, format):
        try:
            problem = ProblemsModel.objects.get(pk=pk)
            serializer = ProblemsSerializer(problem)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=HTTP_200_OK)
        except ProblemsModel.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get_list(self, request, format):
        problems = ProblemsModel.objects.all()
        serializer = ProblemsSerializer(problems, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=HTTP_200_OK)

    def get(self, request, pk=None, format=None):
        if pk:
            return self.get_object(request, pk, format)
        else:
            return self.get_list(request, format)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = ProblemsSerializer(data=request.DATA)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            self.pre_save(request, serializer.object)
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
        try:
            problem = ProblemsModel.objects.get(pk=pk)
            serializer = ProblemsSerializer(problem, data=request.DATA)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                self.pre_save(request, serializer.object)
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data, status=HTTP_200_OK)
            else:
                return Response(serializer.errors, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        except ProblemsModel.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        try:
            problem = ProblemsModel.objects.get(pk=pk)
            problem.delete()
            return Response(status=HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
        except ProblemsModel.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

the permission-checks for objects are done by DRF in the method `APIView.check_object_permissions`.

Since you don't use the `GenericAPIView`, you define your own `get_object` method and you have to call `check_object_permissions` yourself. Since you are mis-using get_object a bit, you have to check for GET (single), PUT and DELETE

```
self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
```

Perhaps have a better look at the [DRF Generic Views](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views), since your use-case looks much like them. Normally `get_object` should only return an object and check the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to share my solution for ViewSets.
I want superuser to have permission for all, but for staff, only access to his own details

This is how you can use permissions (for a get single object call)

My setup: Django 4, python 3.11

My API class:

```
class StaffViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = StaffSerializer
    queryset = user.objects.filter(is_staff=True)

    def get_permissions(self):
        """
        Instantiates and returns the list of permissions that this view requires.
        """
        if self.action in ["list", "create", "delete"]:
            permission_classes = [LoggedInSuperUser]
        else:
            permission_classes = [LoggedInSuperUser|LoggedInStaff]
        return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]
```

My Permissions class:

```
class LoggedInStaff(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return all([request.user.is_staff, request.user.is_authenticated])

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if obj.email == request.user.email:
            return True
        return False


class LoggedInSuperUser(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return all([request.user.is_superuser, request.user.is_authenticated])

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return all([request.user.is_superuser, request.user.is_authenticated])
```