# detail_route on viewset not following object level permissions

Tags: django-rest-framework

This is my ViewSet:

```
class PageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Page.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PageSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user, location=self.request.user.userextended.location)

    @detail_route(methods=['post'])
    def add(self, request, pk=None):
        try:
            page = Page.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except:
            content = {'Page': ['The page you are trying to add no longer exists.']}
            return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        page.users.add(request.user)

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

And this is my `IsOwnerOrReadOnly` permission:

```
class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Allow only the owner (and admin) of the object to make changes (i.e. 
    do PUT, PATCH, DELETE and POST requests. A user is an
    owner of an object if the object has an attribute
    called owner and owner is == request.user. If the
    object is a User object or if the object does not have
    an owner attribute, then return object == request.user.
    """

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        print('In permission')
        return True

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        print('In object level permission')
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        if request.user.is_staff:
            return True

        try:
            return obj.owner == request.user
        except: # if obj does not have an owner property (e.g. users don't

                # have owner properties).
            return obj == request.user
```

The problem is, I can post to `add-detail` as an authenticated user even when I am not the owner of the page. When I do the post request, it only prints `In permission` twice and never prints `In object level permission`. My question is, since it is a `detail_route` and is clearly using a `{lookup}` object (see here which shows that it is using an object: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/), how come the `has_object_permission()` function from the permission class does not get called? How come only the regular `has_permission()` function gets called?

I'm hoping for someone to link to a documentation which verifies that even for `detail_route`, only `has_permission` gets called.

Edit: This is not a duplicate of [Django rest framework ignores has_object_permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22561698/django-rest-framework-ignores-has-object-permission) because I am using a ModelViewSet which inherits from GenericAPIView (as mentioned in the documentation: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset).

Comment: @Ivan This is not a duplicate of the post you linked to because I am using ModelViewSet which inherits from GenericAPIView (I also edited my post to add this information).

Comment: The point is the same that in the accepted answer, it's up to you to call `check_object_permissions` in `add`.

Comment: @Ivan The answer says: "The permission-checks for objects are done by DRF in the method APIView.check_object_permissions. 
Since you don't use the GenericAPIView, you define your own get_object method and you have to call check_object_permissions yourself." However, I do use it (I inherit from it) and for all my other PageViewSet requests (PUT, PATCH and DELETE), `check_object_permissions` of `IsOwnerOrReadOnly` gets called perfectly fine. It's just that it doesn't work for my detail_route function. Wondering if in the documentation it says `detail_route` does not use object level permissions?

Comment: This is what I am trying to say: it's not the router that checks permissions. When you define an action which you are routing to it's up to you to call `check_object_permissions` if you are not using `get_object`. I don't see it in your `add`.

Comment: I will post a complete answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22561698/django-rest-framework-ignores-has-object-permission). There are some differences but the point is the same: `check_object_permissions` is not called.

Although you are inheriting from `ModelViewSet` you are not using its `get_object` in your `add` method to retrieve the page. It is `get_object` that calls `check_object_permissions` (not the router) for retrieve, update etc., so obviously it doesn't get called.

To fix it, do the following:

```
class PageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    # ...    

    @detail_route(methods=['post'])
    def add(self, request, pk=None):
        page = self.get_object()
        page.users.add(request.user)

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

or just do `self.check_object_permissions(page)` yourself somewhere in your implementation.