# Django Rest Framework check_object_permissions not being called

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am trying to make sure the user has permission to view the object they are calling. Here is my permissions class:

```
from rest_framework import permissions


class IsOwner(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Custom permission to only allow owners of an object to do actions.
    """
    message = 'You must be the owner of this object.'

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        print("CHECK THAT I GOT HERE")
        return obj.user == request.user
```

And here is my ViewSet:

```
class TopLevelJobViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsOwner,)
    serializer_class = TopLevelJobSerializer
    queryset = TopLevelJob.objects.all()
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, RelatedOrderingFilter]
    filter_class = TopLevelJobFilter
    ordering_fields = '__all__'
```

The`has_object_permissions` is not being called, anyone visiting the endpoint is able to access all the objects.

Why is this? How do I get `has_object_permissions` to get called?

This post: [Django rest framework ignores has_object_permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22561698/django-rest-framework-ignores-has-object-permission) talks about it being an issue with not having `GenericAPIView`. But `ModelViewSet` has `GenericViewSet` which has `generics.GenericAPIView`. Is something overriding this somewhere?

EDIT: My issue was that I was calling `list` instead of `get`. How can I only returns objects in `list` that belong to a user?

This link: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-the-current-user shows I could implement something like this:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    username = self.kwargs['username']
    return Purchase.objects.filter(purchaser__username=username)
```

This seems to violate DRY if I have to add this to every viewset. Is there a way to turn this into a `permissions` class that I could always call?

Comment: You can subclass the `get_queryset` part as well, so you can do that without violating DRY as well.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit here? Would this mean my viewset inherits from another class with a custom `get_queryset`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement [custom generic filtering [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#custom-generic-filtering). For example:

```
class IsOwnerFilter(filters.BaseFilterBackend):

    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        return queryset.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

Then you can add this to your `ModelViewSet`:

```
class TopLevelJobViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsOwner,)
    serializer_class = TopLevelJobSerializer
    queryset = TopLevelJob.objects.all()
    filter_backends = [IsOwnerFilter, DjangoFilterBackend, RelatedOrderingFilter]
    filter_class = TopLevelJobFilter
    ordering_fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: This worked. Just an edit: it should be `queryset.filter`, not `queryset.objects.filter`